# meaning '' the written characters'' in contex

Tags: meaning-in-context

what does that mean''written character'' in this contex?

Strangers bearing gifts(trip tips):
Beware what you offer your host. Pass up chrysanthemums in argentina(they denote funerals), clocks in China (**the written characters** resemble those for death) and red pens in south Korea(red ink conveys unfriendliness)

Comment: I would assume that it means that characters that appear hand-drawn use a style that creates that resemblance.

Comment: you mean death in chiness is written in a style which resembles clock?

Comment: @I'm guessing that when the characters are arrayed on the clock they may appear to spell out "death" or some such.

Comment: Thanks my friend. I did some more searches through and got this:

Comment: Clocks - Bad Luck

In Chinese, saying 'giving a clock' (送钟 sòng zhōng /song jong/) sounds exactly like the Chinese words for 'attending a funeral ritual' (送终 sòng zhōng) and thus it is bad luck to gift clocks or watches.

Comment: In my country, gifting knives indicates that you want to "cut" the friendship.

Comment: @Cascabel Like this then? [¿Por qué los cuchillos no se regalan?](https://www.todo-cuchillos.com/por-que-los-cuchillos-no-se-regalan/)

Comment: @tchrist Yup....I actually collect knives, and am learning how to make them. I once suggested to my wife that I would like to gift some of  my finer hand-crafted blades to family and friends, and she was horrified....another weirdie is placing a broom behind the main entrance door _upside down_ before someone arrives. It means you want to sweep the people out of your house....or maybe it is non-verbal communication.

Answer (score 1):

I have almost no Chinese so depend on web search. Nevertheless from my naive viewpoint, here is some of what I find.

First here is one character representation or translation for *death*:
[image: death]

and here is the character representation or translation for *clock*:

[image]

On comparing these characters you will see that the left hand half of each there is a similarity. It may be even stronger depending on the precise way the characters are written. This presumably has lead to the association of clocks with death. I hope an expert on Chinese calligraphy and characters will be able to do this better than I have been able to do.

Comment: In a comment to his post the OP says that the phrases for 'giving a clock' and 'attending a funeral' _sound_ identical whereas the characters for 'clock' and 'death' don't look much alike at all. I think the person writing the advice has read something inaccurate and reproduced it.